# How do I change value in filtered cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet full of different vacancies and they go in order of the date advertised, but they have different departments within that and I need them numbered. I only need the filtered departments numbered as the dates have to be chronologically ordered.

Is there a way of numbering just the filtered cells without numbered all of the data?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood it rigth but try this:

1. First unfilter everything.
2. Then in an additional column add this formula `=SUBTOTAL(103,$A$2:$A2)` and fill down to as many rows as necessary bearing in mind that your data starts at row 2 and column A is something like an identification of the vacancy.
3. Finally you can filter however you want and only filtered data will be numbered.